# How to use JOptionPane to create a menu

Tags: java, user-interface, switch-statement, joptionpane

I have created a system class that has different methods for displaying details of a computer system.

```
import java.util.Properties;

public class System_Y3881268 
{
    // the attributes
    private String make;
    private String model;
    private int speed;
    private int memorySize;
    private double hardDiskSize;
    private double purchaseCost;

     // the methods

     // the constructor
    public System_Y3881268(String makeIn, String modelIn, int speedIn) 
    {
        make = makeIn;
        model = modelIn;
        speed = 2;
    }

    // methods to set the corresponding attributes- mutator methods
        public void setMemory(int memorySizeIn) 
        {
            memorySize = memorySizeIn;
        }

        public void setHardDisk(double hardDiskSizeIn) 
        {
            hardDiskSize = hardDiskSizeIn;
        }

        public void setPurchaseCost(double purchaseCostIn) 
        {
            purchaseCost = purchaseCostIn;
        }

    // methods to return attribute values- accessor methods
    public String getMake() 
    {
        return make;
    }

    public String getModel() 
    {
        return model;
    }

    public int getProcessorSpeed() 
    {
        return speed;
    }

    //display details of the system
    public void displayDetails() 
    {
        System.out.println("*****Computer Details*****");
        System.out.println("Make: " + getMake());
        System.out.println("Model: " + getModel());
        System.out.println("Processor speed; " + getProcessorSpeed() + "GHz");
        System.out.println("Memory size: " + memorySize + " MB"); 
        System.out.println("Hard disk size: " + hardDiskSize + " GB");
        System.out.println("Purchase cost: £" + purchaseCost);
    }

    //check if the hard disk size is below 2GB and print corresponding message   
    public String checkHDStatus(double hardDiskSizeIn) 
    {
        if(hardDiskSizeIn<2) 
        {
            return("Low");
        }

        else 
        {
            return("Ok");
        }
    }

    //Check if the memory size is below 128MB and print corresponding message
    public boolean goodMemorySize(int memorySizeIn) 
    {
        if(memorySizeIn<128) 
        {
            return false;
        }

        else 
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    /*use the checkHDStatus() method and the goodMemorySize() method to diagnose the 
     * system by displaying the appropriate messages*/
    public void diagnoseSystem() 
    {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("*****System Diagnosis*****");
        System.out.println("Hard disk size = " + checkHDStatus(hardDiskSize));
        System.out.println("Memory size Ok = " + goodMemorySize(memorySize));
    }

    //method to display system properties
    public static void displaySystemProperties() 
    {
        Properties pros = System.getProperties();
        pros.get(System.out);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("*****System Properties*****");

        System.out.println("Operating System Architecture: " + System.getProperty("os.arch"));
        System.out.println("Operating System Name: " + System.getProperty("os.name"));
        System.out.println("Operating System Version: " + System.getProperty("os.version"));
        System.out.println("User Account Name: " + System.getProperty("user.name"));
        System.out.println("Java Version: " + System.getProperty("java.version"));
        System.out.println();

        if(System.getProperty("os.name").equals("Windows 10")) 
        {
            System.out.println("Thumbs up! Your operating system is Windows 10");
        }
        else if(System.getProperty("os.name").equals("Linux")) 
        {
            System.out.println("Thumbs down! Your operating system is Linux");
        } 

        else 
        {
            System.out.println("Your choice of operating system is ok");
        }

    }
}
```

I have then created a test system GUI class that uses this information and calls these methods as a drop down menu using a switch statement. The program is not working as it should. It creates a pane with a drop down menu, listing 1-5 as options but when I select choices 1, 2, or 4 it doesn't do anything. It is supposed to display the information from the corresponding methods. I'm not sure how to fix this.

When I select option 3 it displays the input boxes as it should but it doesn't matter what I enter it gives the same result. I believe this is because they are initialized to 0, but I'm not sure how I can initialise it without a number.

Also when I select option 5 it is supposed to exit the program, but it does not and again I don't know how to fix this. There is also an error on this line: while(input != "5"); saying that "input cannot be resolved to a variable"

any advice?

Here is the updated test system GUI code: Although I know have this at the "}));" line at the bottom: Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error, insert "Identifier (" to complete 
     MethodHeaderName
    - Syntax error, insert "SimpleName" to complete 
     QualifiedName

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import com.sun.javafx.binding.MapExpressionHelper.SimpleChange;

public class SystemTestGUI_Y3881268 
{

    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.@invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        private StringBuffer input;

        public void run() {
            createGUI();
        }

        private void createGUI() {


            do {
                String[] choices = { "Select...", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };
                String input = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Select a choice\n1: Print System Details\n2: Diagnose "
                        + "System\n3: Set Details\n4: Print System Properties\n5: Quit the Program", 
                        "Computer System Menu", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, choices, choices[0]);

                System_Y3881268 s;
                switch(input) 
                {

                case "1": 

                    s.displayDetails();

                break;

                case "2": 

                    s.diagnoseSystem();

                break;

                case "3": 

                    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter hard disk size in GB: ");
                    double hardDiskSize = 0;
                    s.setHardDisk(hardDiskSize);
                    if(hardDiskSize<2) 
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hard disk size = Low");
                    }

                    else 
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hard disk size = Ok");
                    }

                    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter memory size in MB: ");
                    int memorySize = 0;
                    s.setMemory(memorySize);
                    if(memorySize<128) 
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Memory Ok = False");
                    }

                    else 
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Memory Ok = True");
                    }

                break;

                case "4": 

                    System_Y3881268.displaySystemProperties();

                break;

                case "5": break;
                default: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter only numbers from 1 - 5");

        }
    }while (!"5".contentEquals(input)




    );}


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System_Y3881268 s=new System_Y3881268("Lenovo", 
                "Ideacentre A340-24IWL", 2);
        s.setHardDisk(2);
        s.setMemory(128);
        s.setPurchaseCost(599);

        s.displayDetails();
        s.diagnoseSystem();
        System_Y3881268.displaySystemProperties();

    }

}));

}
```

Comment: 1) `input` is declared inside the `do`, so, when it gets to the `while` it no longer exists. 2) See [How do I compare Strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) 3) There's no need for those curly braces in the switch cases, if you indent your code correctly it should be easy to understand it without them. 4) Why are you creating methods inside the `Runnable` object?

Comment: What do you mean by 4)? I am a complete newbie and don't really have any idea what I'm doing

Comment: `public void run()` and `private void createGUI()` are both inside `new Runnable() { ... }` and also inside `main(...)` method. This is a wrong way to write your program. Hierarchy should be `Class > Methods` not `Class > Methods > Methods`. Put those 2 methods outside `main`. Then edit your code here to show improvements made